# PHP: preg_match issue

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm having an issue with preg_match, somehow, I'm still new with preg_match and I still can't get it working like what I want.

Here's my data...

String_Length_Location_Time_Degree_Alt

I'm using this preg_match to split up the data into the varibles...

```
preg_match('(?<data1>)_(?<data2>)_(?<data3>)_(?<data4>)_(?<data5>)_(?<data6>)', $str, $matches);
```

And I get the following error "preg_match(): Unknown modifier '_' in **[...][...]**"

Does anyone have an idea what can be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you simply explode on `_`?

Comment: or escape the `_` using `\\`

Comment: PCRE needs a delimiter around the regex.

Comment: @ZackNewsham It doesn't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have any [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).  Delimiters enclose the pattern:

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.

Typically a "modifier" is a character that sets options for the regular expression (case sensitivity, multiline mode, etc.) and comes *after the closing delimiter*.

So, this error message is saying that it thinks you are using `_` as a modifier, because it seems to be after the pattern.  Try enclosing your pattern in the standard delimiter, `/`, as in `/PATTERN_GOES_HERE/`

You also need to *match* something in the capture groups. `.*` will do (match any amount of anything):

```
preg_match('/(?<data1>.*)_(?<data2>.*)_(?<data3>.*)_(?<data4>.*)_(?<data5>.*)_(?<data6>.*)/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => String_Length_Location_Time_Degree_Alt
    [data1] => String
    [1] => String
    [data2] => Length
    [2] => Length
    [data3] => Location
    [3] => Location
    [data4] => Time
    [4] => Time
    [data5] => Degree
    [5] => Degree
    [data6] => Alt
    [6] => Alt
)
```

Alternately, your case looks like a good candidate for `explode`, which separates a string into an array splitting the string every time it comes across a delimiter character, which you would specify as the undescore,  `"_"`.

Comment: This answer is right as far as delimiters go, but it still won't actually capture anything...

Answer (score 0):

Since all of your data is separated by underscore why not use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$data = explode('_', $str);
$data[0] = 'string';
$data[1] = 'Length'; //etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code...

1. You're missing delimiters enclosing your regex.
2. You don't actually capture anything.

### Fix for your code

Not much to say aparat from the added delimiters `/` at each end and the added `.*` to capture *any character* between `_`

```
preg_match('/(?<data1>.*)_(?<data2>.*)_(?<data3>.*)_(?<data4>.*)_(?<data5>.*)_(?<data6>.*)/', $string, $match);
```

## Alternatives

You could easily use the `explode` function for this as your data is merely separated by a character.

If you want to use regex you could also use `preg_match_all` which would make your code much easier to read (assuming that you read regex ;) )

```
$string = "String_Length_Location_Time_Degree_Alt";

$explode = explode('_', $string);
var_dump($explode);

preg_match_all('/_*(.+?)(?:_|$)/',$string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

/**

Output for explode:

array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "String"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Length"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Location"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "Time"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "Degree"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "Alt"
}

Output for preg_match_all:

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "String_"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Length_"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "Location_"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "Time_"
    [4]=>
    string(7) "Degree_"
    [5]=>
    string(3) "Alt"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "String"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Length"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "Location"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "Time"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "Degree"
    [5]=>
    string(3) "Alt"
  }
}


*/
```